# CSS Hover Flicker

Tags: css

I've had a look at other questions and answers, but it doesn't seem to be helping me at all - this hover effect works perfect on Safari, there's four directions, left, right, up and down that the first layer slide in said direction(s). But on Chrome, there's no sliding action and there's a flicker. Any ideas?

codepen.io/anon/pen/VYQQbK

Comment: same flicker in IE11 and FireFox 35. time to code it from scratch mate.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping not - is there any better way you'd suggest? I'm thinking I'll just use jQuery to avoid z-index issues.

Comment: i was kidding. check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the

```
.left:hover {
    left: -100%;
}
```

to

```
.left:hover {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
```

here is a fixed example:

```css
html, body, .container, .box {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1,
h3,
h4,
h5,
body {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'oswald';
}

h2,p {
 width: 75%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 16px;
}
p {
 padding: 15px;
}
img {
 width: 120px;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: 3px solid white;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 min-height: 100%;
}
.box {
 width: 33.3%;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
.front-layer, .back-layer {
 height: 100%;
}
.front-layer {
 z-index: 1;
  background-color: purple;
  position: absolute;
}
.back-layer {
 z-index: -1;
 background-color: #2BAEFF;
  position: realtive;
}
.front-layer > div, .back-layer > div {
 top: 10%;
 position: relative;
}

.up, .down, .left, .right {
 -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
 -webkit-transform: 1.2s;
 transition: 1.2s;
 transform: 1.2s;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Safari, Chrome & Opera support */
   transform-style: preserve-3d; /* IE support */
}
.up:hover, .down:hover, .left:hover, .right:hover {
 -webkit-transition: all 1.2s;
 -webkit-transform: 1.2s;
 transition: all 1.2s;
 transform: 1.2s;
 opacity: 0;
}

.left:hover {
 margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="box"><!-- info box start -->
  <div class="front-layer left">
   <div>
    <img class="click" src="../Boxes/imgs/person.png">  
     <h2>John Snow</h2>
      <p>Meet John, our resident content editor working on our advertising content and managing the marketing.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back-layer">
   <div>
    <img src="../Boxes/imgs/goofy.png">
    <p>Hey, my name is John, and here's some gibberish. Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet candy canes muffin gingerbread I love. Dragée pudding jelly-o candy canes cake tart pastry sesame snaps. I love liquorice I love apple pie.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- info box end -->
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

there is the trick:

```
.up:hover {
    margin-top: -100%;
}
.down:hover {
    margin-top: 200%;
}
.left:hover {
    margin-left: -100%;
}
.right:hover {
    margin-left: 200%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, that's awesome, but on a layout like this:

codepen.io/anon/pen/VYQQbK

The last 3 just fade, there's no slide as it where.

Comment: @BillyPurvis instead of pulling them `-100%`, push them from the other side to `200%`. check my update

Comment: you might also wanna add `overflow:hidden;` to the very first css block to get rid of the annoying scrollbars

Comment: That's awesome man! Thanks, this has been frustrating me all night, I haven't thought to do it that way - also, added the overflow:hidden to my code. Thanks and much appreciated!